# Modify quarkus uber jar with 3rd party dependency

Tags: quarkus

I have application `some-aplication-1.0.0-runner.jar` packaged in uber jar and I need to enhance this uber jar with another dependent jar. I just copied classes from dependency into uber jar, but new classes are **invisible for CDI** because Quarkus solves dependencies during the build stage.

We had the same application `some-aplication-1.0.0.jar` in Kumuluzee, we just copied the new dependency do lib directory in uber jar and worked everything fine. Quarkus does not have any lib directory in uber jar.

Is there anyway to extend the already released uber jar in Quarkus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do will **not** in Quarkus because Quarkus needs to know all dependencies at build-time in order to augment the application.

This means you need to have all your jars in the `pom.xml` (or `build.gradle`).